# Using drivers to have the camera focus on the lowest object

Tags: camera, constraints, drivers

I have a physics simulator with balls rolling down a slide. Each ball has an empty attached to it. I would like to have my camera automatically focus ("track to") on the ball that is lowest on the z axis.

I have "track to" constraints (on the camera) for each ball and manually keyframe the influence to 1 (and the rest to 0) in the animation. As the objects are changing places a lot, it is very tedious.

[image]

Is there a way to do this with drivers, or is there a better way?

Comment: if it’s the same ball through the whole course, you can just use the Track To constraint. If the ball changes, I would use several constraints and animate their influence. Unless the animation is super long or which ball is the correct one changes a whole lot, that bit of automation is probably not worth all the trigonometry.

Comment: Thank you Thelabcat. I am trying to track multiple. i've been doing it manually, was curious to see if there was another way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to do that with help of geometry nodes.

[image]

1. Camera "Track to" Empty.

[image]

2. Empty "Shrink wrap" to Geonodes Setup

[image]

3. All geonodes setup:

[image]

4. Inside "Location_To_Point" Group:

[image]

So what is going on here? :)
Geometry nodes create very small Ico Sphere at the location of the lowest ball. Empty drop on the surface of this Ico Sphere. That is why camera can track lowest ball.

File for fun:
[image]

Comment: Great solution! I saw already from other answers that you love GN too and you have a huge knowledge in this area. Of course +1 too.  And I also love provided blend files in answers as well because you can directly check it out instead of rebuilding for hours.

Comment: @Chris I am happy that you like it. :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the additional detail! This is fantastic.

Answer (score 10):

If we only need to track altitude, we can do this without drivers, very easily, by using several floor constraints:

[image]

Here, the empty, which has an elevated pre-constraint position (z=10000 ought to be safe), is floored to the world -Z of each of the three Suzannes, so it can never rise above the world position of the lowest.  The camera then tracks this empty.  If we want the empty to lie at the base of the lowest Suzanne, we can tune the Offset parameters of the constraints.

We could do this with a driver, but it's more work.  We need a separate variable for the world space Z of every item we want to track, after which we can use a min(var1, min(var2, min(...))) scripted expression to get the lowest of these values and track that.  Setting up drivers is more work (and worse for performance) than just quickly setting up a few constraints via select, shift select, ctrl shift c create constraint.

A different way to handle it, that will track the mesh rather than the object, and will track not just altitude but the lowest point, is to shrinkwrap to a collection containing all the objects.  We can do that with, say, a non-rendering boolean union:

[image]

This is probably a waste of performance, but it's very fast to set up with any number of objects.  A single vertex is boolean unioned with a collection, then disabled for renders.  The empty starts at z= -10000 and then shrinkwraps; its initial position is what guarantees it gets the lowest point of any mesh.

Comment: maybe i am too dumb...but if i move my 3 objects above the ground (0), the empty stays at 0...so it "works" only if at least one object is at z <= 0.

Comment: Thank you Nathan. This is getting me closer to understanding. I am trying to have the camera automagically "track to" the lowest object in the simulation. I have "track to" constraints for each object (balls) and manually keyframe the influence to 1 (and the rest to 0) in the animation. As the objects are changing places a lot, it is very tedious. I've also tried having the camera "track to" an empty and then have the empty "track to" the objects, but I'm basically doing the same thing by having to change the influence manually. My knowledge is still new to all this. Thanks again.

Comment: @Chris The empty will only ever lower, so needs to start at an elevated position; z = 10000 ought to be safe.  But I didn't think this through or test sufficiently: it will only ever track altitude via this method.  So I guess I have to edit or delete this answer.

Comment: No, don't do that. There is a lot of additional valuable information in it. And you got 10 upvotes and raising...so i am not the only one who thinks that your answer is valuable! +1

Comment: Thanks again Nathan and Chris. I really appreciate you taking the time to help me. :)

Answer (score 7):

I would use Python for that. Open a text editor, and paste this code:

```
import bpy


def getMinObject():

    col = bpy.data.collections["RigidBodies"]

    minZ = 1000000

    minObject = col.objects[0]

    for obj in col.objects:

        if obj.matrix_world.translation.z < minZ:
            minObject = obj
            minZ = obj.matrix_world.translation.z
            print("set to obj", obj)

    return minObject

def my_handler(scene):
    print("in handler", scene.frame_current)
    cam = bpy.data.objects["Camera"]
    cam.constraints[0].target = getMinObject()

def register():
    bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(my_handler)

def unregister():
    bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.remove(my_handler)



register()
```

Click on run script:

[image]

Then start your rigid body simulation.

Here you can see the code in action:

[image]

How does the code work?

The function getMinObject() loops over all objects which are in a collection called "RigidBodies".
Whenever the current z position of the current looped object is lower than the lowest z position, the lowest z position will be saved in minZ and the object will be saved in minObject.
The functions then return the object with the lowest z position.

```
def register():
    bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(my_handler)

def unregister():
    bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.remove(my_handler)
```

The register function ensures that the function my_handler will be called after each frame.
The unregister function does the opposite: it removes this automatism.

```
def my_handler(scene):
    print("in handler", scene.frame_current)
    cam = bpy.data.objects["Camera"]
    cam.constraints[0].target = getMinObject()
```

The my_handler function will be called after each frame. It saves the camera object in `cam` and then changes the target of the first constraint (which should be track to) to the object which is calculated/set by the function getMinObject.

Note: This code is for sure not super safe and not super clean.
It just works.

But, it is hardcoded and you have to ensure these things, that it runs:

1. You have to have a collection called "RigidBodies" with your objects in it, which should be considered for the track to functionality. These collection must not be empty.
2. you camera must be named "Camera"
3. your camera must have a "track to" constraint as first constraint

[image]

---

With drivers I would do it like this:

[image]

So it basically just gets all z locations and uses the minimum values of these.

[image]

Comment: This is great, thank you Chris! Sorry, I'm still trying to figure out how to ask my question as my knowledge is limited. Is there a way to have the camera "track to" the object that is lowest? I am manually setting keyframe on "track to" influence. Because there are a bunch of objects I am going through the list of constraints (on the camera) and setting everything to "0" and the lowest to "1". Maybe even if there is an easier way to set the keyframe for all the "track to" constraints at once? Thanks again!

Comment: sorry, missed somehow that you wanted to have the trackto object changed. I updated my answer with a python solution.

Comment: Brilliant!!! This is exactly what I needed. Thank you for showing me the way. Gratitude! :D

Comment: Glad I could help. Thank you very much! Sorry that I missed the right answer in my first try.

Comment: Chris I upvoted your solution because scripts are so cool and hardcore. Chris and @Admbro please don't miss my alternativ answer. As always I do it with geonodes. And I want to know your opinion. :)